# Open a file URL and read it in PHP?

Tags: php, file, fopen

Given a URL that points to a file, how can I open it and read the contents in PHP?

```
$file = fopen("http://www.alinktomyfile.com/kasfafa", "r");
```

This line has an error. The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) say to use stream_get_contents() for a URL, however I get an error:

```
$file_contents = stream_get_contents($file);
fclose($file);
```

Error:

Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/donald/Desktop/php_boilerplate.php on line 24

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please leave a comment explaining why. Thanks

Comment: I believe `filesize()` does not work with HTTP. You should just use `file_get_contents()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `file_get_contents()`

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.alinktomyfile.com/kasfafa");
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, do you know why file_get_contents is preferable over stream_get_contents?

Comment: Identical to file_get_contents(), except that stream_get_contents() operates on an already open stream resource and returns the remaining contents in a string, up to maxlength bytes and starting at the specified offset.